# Return to previous activity using onBackPressed() without finish()?

Tags: android, android-activity, return, back, pressed

I have 2 activities. Activity1 lists a bunch of songs and when one is selected, it go plays the selected song in Activity2. Now I can press Back to go back to Activity1 but I overridden the onBackPressed to start an animation when it is pressed. Since I did that, it never goes back to the previous activity. I don't want to call finish() because it will stop the music and the moveTaskToBack method just hides my whole application. Basically what I want to do is have Activity2 play an animation and go back to Activity1 without finishing or hiding the app.
I don't know if making a new Intent to go back is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call
 super.onBackPressed () 
just after your 
Animation code finishes.

No need to do anything else...

Comment: or call finish() when animation ends